# v-data-table-server not updating component in the table template

Tags: vue.js, dom, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify `v-data-table-server` ([docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/server-side-tables/)) which updates itself by fetching data from API.

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table-server
    v-if="events.length > 0"
    v-model:items-per-page="events_limit"
    :headers="headers"
    :items-length="events_total"
    :items="events"
    :loading="loading"
    item-key="e_id"
    @update:options="loadItems">

      <template #item.e_created_at="{ item }">
        <event-date :initialDate="item.raw.e_created_at" />
        {{ item.raw.e_created_at }}
      </template>
      
      <template #item.e_status="{ item }">
        {{ item.raw.e_status }}
      </template>
  </v-data-table-server>
</template>

<script>
import userService from "user.service";
import EventDate from "EventDate.vue";

export default {
  name: "Events",
  props: ["page"],
  computed: {},
  components: {
    EventDate,
  },
  data: () => ({
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    events: [],
    events_offset: 0,
    events_limit: 10,
    loading: true,
    headers: [
      {
        title: "Date",
        align: "start",
        sortable: true,
        key: "e_created_at",
      },
      {
        title: "Result",
        align: "start",
        sortable: true,
        key: "e_status",
      },
    ],
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.loadItems({ page: 1, itemsPerPage: 10 });
  },
  methods: {
    loadItems({ page, itemsPerPage, sortBy }) {
      this.loading = true;
      userService
        .get_events({
          limit: itemsPerPage,
          offset: (page - 1) * itemsPerPage,
          sort_by: sortBy,
        })
        .then(
          (response) => {
            this.events_total = response.events_total;
            this.events = response.events;
            this.loading = false;
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I also have an `EventDate` component which is simply formatting the date:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ formattedDate }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "EventDate",
  props: {
    initialDate: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formattedDate() {
      const dt = new Date(this.date);
      const day = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
      const month = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
      const year = dt.getFullYear();
      const hours = dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
      const minutes = dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
      const seconds = dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");

      return `${day}.${month}.${year} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.date = this.initialDate; // Set the initial date when component is created
  },
};
</script>
```

When the first page is fetched, everything seems normal: components are showing formatted data.

[image]

But when I jump to another page, though I get correct values from API and I even see them in the table, `EventDate` component instances are not updated:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, ChatGPT got it right.

> When the table updates its data from the API, Vue tries to be as efficient as possible in re-rendering the components. In some cases, components with similar properties are re-used rather than destroyed and recreated. As a result, the created() lifecycle hook might not be called again when you change the page.

I added this to my `EventDate.vue`:

```js
export default {
  ...,
  watch: {
    initialDate(newVal) {
      this.date = newVal;
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

And now both parts of the cell are updated when I navigate through table pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same page number (page number 1) every time, that's the reason the data is the same on every page.

```
mounted() {
  this.loadItems({ page: 1, itemsPerPage: 10 });
},
```

As I can see, you are taking the page number as props, so use prop data-

```
mounted() {
  this.loadItems({ page: this.page, itemsPerPage: 10 });
},
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, `page: this.page` does not help, it actually prevents any initial loading. As you can see, I use `page: 1` only when the component is mounted, to get the initial values from API.

Comment: My previous code works well to fetch data from API. Please notice that in every cell I print out first the component `EventDate` where I pass the date by `<event-date :initialDate="item.raw.e_created_at" />`, and then print out just the prop `{{ item.raw.e_created_at }}`. Jumping from page to page, the latter is changed, but not the former (like the component is not re-rendered with the new prop).